# Appending dictionaries to list within a dictionary by asking if input is a list

Tags: python, list, isinstance

I am working with a list of dictionaries within a dictionary.

```python
authors=['a','b']

new_item={'itemType': 'journalArticle',
 'title': '',
 'creators': [{'creatorType': 'author', 'firstName': '', 'lastName': ''}]}


if type(authors) == 'list':
    new_item['creators'] = []
    for name in authors:
        new_item['creators'].append(dict({'creatorType': 'author', 'name': name}))
else:
    new_item['creators'] = [{'creatorType': 'author', 'name': authors}]

new_item
```

Why does the above code give this:

```
{'itemType': 'journalArticle',
 'title': '',
 'creators': [{'creatorType': 'author', 'name': ['a', 'b']}]}
```

instead of this:

```
{'itemType': 'journalArticle',
 'title': '',
 'creators': [{'creatorType': 'author', 'name': 'a'},{'creatorType': 'author', 'name': 'b'}]}
```

Comment: `type(authors) == list` instead of `type(authors) == 'list'`

Comment: `if type(authors) == 'list':` is not the correct way to determine if `authors` is a list. Use `if isinstance(authors, list):`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this simple way,

```
authors=['a','b']
new_item={'itemType': 'journalArticle',
 'title': '',
 'creators': [{'creatorType': 'author', 'firstName': '', 'lastName': ''}]}

if isinstance(authors, list):
    new_item['creators'] = [{'creatorType': 'author', 'name': name} for name in authors]
else:
    new_item['creators'] = [{'creatorType': 'author', 'name': authors}]

print(new_item)
```

**Output:**

```
{'itemType': 'journalArticle', 'title': '', 'creators': [{'creatorType': 'author', 'name': 'a'}, {'creatorType': 'author', 'name': 'b'}]}
```

Comment: You could replace ``type(authors) is list`` with ``isinstance(authors, list)`` which would be more appropriate.

Comment: What's the difference between the 2 expressions? `type(authors) == 'list'`  also returns `True` when `authors` variable is a list.

Comment: type command returns only strings, so the proper way to check is either by using isinstance or membership operator